# Custom fields doesnt work well with any postTAB plugin

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, tabs

Here is my problem:
I tried to implement custom fields (text) within a post tab. I tried many post tab plugins and   the imlementation to template was succesfull... Unfortunately, the content of the custom field is showing always on TOP of the content and not inside... I tried eveything and every plugin, still same issue. 
I tried so far: WP UI, Post UI, Easy responsive tabs, everything.

My following code:

```
<?php 
 $tabContent =  the_field('kotoba');
 echo do_shortcode('[restabs alignment="osc-tabs-left" responsive="false"]

[restab title="Tab number 1" active="active"]'.$tabContent.'[/restab]
[restab title="Tab number 1" active="active"]'. the_field('text_field').'[/restab]
[restab title="Tab number 4"]Tab 4 content goes here.[/restab][/restabs]');


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you use ACF for your custom field, right?

In that case, replace the function "the_field" in your code with "get_field".

the_field echoes the field already, so the field is echoed before your tab shortcodes return from the function do_shortcode and get echoed, which results in "having the content of the field before the tab" stuff.

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: Wow, works finally! I cant say how much I'm in debt to you because nowhere could I find the solution and everywhere else people use the_field.